# SharePoint 2010 Http Throttling Errors

Tags: service-applications

[image]

The sharepoint 2010 site is very very slow.it tooks 1 mints to load and that time

we received above error in one of the WFE eventlog and we checked sharepoint log(trace log) also same error

can u advice me regarding Root cause of this issue ?

Is it purly sharepoint configuration issue  else Code issue or Network/other suporting team issue ?

but we checked with all teams Network/other suporting team and everything fine

So Please Provide Root Cause (RCA) for this issue ? why its happening only one WFE

if we restart corresponding WFE and sites working well

Environment details : 2 WFE,2 APP and 1 sql(standalone)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following TechNet article on 8032 and 8062 events.  One or more of the suggested resolutions may help you address you problem or at least point you in the direction of a resolution:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513044.aspx

I had a customer with this issue about a year ago and they ultimately had to add more WFEs, but you may or may not be facing a resource load problem...could be something with your config as the other proposed resolutions suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell what is going on. Use the resource monitor to check the WFE's for CPU, disk I/O, network, IIS connections/requests per second/queued requests etc. It could be anything from custom code, bad configuration to faulty hardware. The error you see is basically that SharePoint starts throttling to be able to catch up with incoming requests.

Bottom line; to be able to help you out, we really need some more information. Can you see other errors in the trace logs and event logs (check system, application and security). Have you installed custom code? etc

Comment: YES..installed custom code lot..such as webparts, custom webparts and etc.